# Azure APIM policy: Set default value for requestParameter

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, apim

I want to set a hardcoded default value for my @RequestParam variable for sometime.

Eg: UI sends-->  url.com/v1/apiName?fruits=apple,mango

```
we want -->  url.com/v1/apiName?fruits=apple,mango,banana
```

Reason for this: UI calls this API they send 2 default values(unfortunately hardcoded) we introduced 1 new value. Their deployment will take time, so for time being, we want to override their inputs.

New to APIM, so need some help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to re-write the uri and you can do that using the re-write uri policy https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-transformation-policies#RewriteURL

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the "set-query-parameter"-policy?

```
<set-query-parameter name="fruits" exists-action="override">
    <value>apple,mango,banana</value>
</set-query-parameter>
```

Comment: Thank you I tried it and got the result.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rewrite the value, first you need to get the value and then add your part.
You could use "set-query-parameter" snippet method to do this.

```
<set-query-parameter name="fruits" exists-action="override">
  <value>@{
    string fruits = context.Request.OriginalUrl.Querys["fruits"]; // apple mango
    return $"{fruits},banana"; // concatenation
  }</value>
</set-query-parameter>
```

This way you'll get the original value from the request and add yours to it. 
2 urls you'll need working with api management + some small knowledge in C# (Google it's enough for that)  
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-policy-expressions 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-advanced-policies